# iOS 8 self sizing cells don't work with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and numberOfLines = 0?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios8, autolayout

I can't get iOS 8 self sizing cells to work with the default cell style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and numberOfLines = 0. It seems that only default cell styles with multiple labels have this issue. The basic style works fine.

Here is sample project demoing the issue:
https://github.com/stevemoser/SelfSizingDemo-DefaultCellStyle

Original code taken from this blog post that uses a custom table view cell:
http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: It seems that way. You'll have to use a custom `UITableViewCell` class with your own constraints, as the built-in styles don't appear to rely on exposed constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The basic cell types totally support self-sizing cells....You just need to remember to set the

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Add those 2 lines and like magic it will work for you

Comment: Hmm... I did. Do you have a working sample project that has multiline labels? When I modify any of the examples out there to use a default cell style and set numberOfLines = 0 they fail.

Comment: Throw up the code you wrote because you shouldn't need more than those 2 lines to get self-sizing cells working with the basic cell types. Setting the estimatedRowHeight is required!

Comment: I didn't write any code. :) Just modified a the storyboard in a working project that had those two lines of code. Lets see if I can quickly post it.

Comment: Make sure the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method is returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension if you are using that method

Comment: I'm not using that method. I edited my question with a sample project.

Comment: Hmm well if you didn't end up doing the constraints properly for the name/address label it would screw up the sizing. Try removing the name/address labels and getting it to work with the built in textLabel then add in the other labels.

Comment: Ah, I think we have a misunderstanding. I'm not laying out the cell. I'm using a default cell style.

Comment: What I mean is by adding more subviews even to a default cell style and adding constraints it will alter the cell's ability to self-size, one or more of those constraints are probably wrong

Comment: I've determined that it only happens on default cell styles with more than one label (UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle). When I try to add a label to default cell style I can't seem to add constraints between my labels and the default cell's label in IB. I imagine I could do it in code though.

Comment: You can only do that in code yes, but almost all the time if your adding more subviews then ignore the cell's built in textLabel and just add your own and do the constraints yourself.

Comment: That feels like it defeats the purpose of using the default cell style in the first place. Why not use a custom cell at that point?

Comment: Yeah almost every table view cell you make will require a custom subclass. The built in cell style is rarely used as-is. A settings screen is a good example where you may use it as-is, but thats about it.